# Logstash input using proxy

Tags: proxy, logstash

I'm having a little trouble while using Logstash and http_poller as an input plugin. I would like to send my http requests through a proxy, but the only documentation I could find is:

```
<li> Value type is <<string,string>>
* There is no default value for this setting.
```

How can I define the IP of my proxy and a specific port to use?

Comment: After a few weeks of research, I found the solution:
You just have to specify the host/port within brackets;

proxy => {
                host => "IP"
                port => "PORT"
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few weeks of research, I found the solution: 
You just have to specify the host/port within brackets;

```
proxy => { 
    host => "IP" 
    port => "PORT" 
}
```